# Value cannot be serialized from npm library import

Tags: qwik, qwikjs

```
  import { createClient } from '@propelauth/javascript'
  const store = useStore({client: null, loggedIn: null})
  useVisibleTask$(async (ctxt) => {
    store.client =  await createClient({ authUrl: 'https://91205364487.propelauthtest.com' })
    store.loggedIn = store.client.getAuthenticationInfoOrNull(true)
})
```

Results in an error: Error: Value cannot be serialized in _.addLoggedInChangeObserver, because it's a function named "addLoggedInChangeObserver". You might need to convert it to a QRL using $(fn): const addLoggedInChangeObserver = $(addLoggedInChangeObserver(loggedInChangeObserver) { const hasObserver = clientState.observers.includes(loggedInChangeObserver); if (hasObserver) { console.error("Observer has been attached already."); } else if (!loggedInChangeObserver) { console.error("Cannot add a null observer"); } else { clientState.observers.push(loggedInChangeObserver); } }); Please check out https://qwik.builder.io/docs/advanced/qrl/ for more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store must always serializable but if you want to store non serializable property inside store you can use `noSerialize()` function and that property will be discarded on server when application is paused and only available in your browser.

Qwik docs
https://qwik.builder.io/tutorial/store/no-serialize/

```js
import {
  component$,
  useStore,
  type NoSerialize,
  useVisibleTask$,
  noSerialize,
} from "@builder.io/qwik";
import {
  type IAuthClient,
  createClient,
  type AuthenticationInfo,
} from "@propelauth/javascript";

type Store = {
  client: NoSerialize<IAuthClient> | null;
  loggedIn: NoSerialize<AuthenticationInfo> | null;
};
export default component$(() => {
  const store = useStore<Store>({ client: null, loggedIn: null });
  useVisibleTask$(async () => {
    const client = await createClient({
      authUrl: "https://91205364487.propelauthtest.com",
    });
    const loggedIn = await client.getAuthenticationInfoOrNull(true);
    store.client = noSerialize(client);
    if (loggedIn) {
      store.loggedIn = noSerialize(loggedIn);
    }
  });
  return <pre>{JSON.stringify(store, null, 4)}</pre>;
});
```